# Angular2 declaring new object and getting /traceur 404

Tags: angular

File item.ts

```
export class SearchTerm{
  term: string;
  filters: string;

  constructor(term: string, filters: string){
     this.term = term;
     this.filters = filters;
  }
}
```

File: item-search.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Optional} from '@angular/core';
  import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
  import { ItemSearchService } from './item-search.service';
  import { SearchTerm} from './item';

  @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'item-search',
    templateUrl: '/views/item-search.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['/views/item-search.component.css'],
    providers: [ItemSearchService],

  })
  export class ItemSearchComponent implements OnInit {


    searchTerm: SearchTerm;

    constructor(
      private itemSearchService: ItemSearchService,
      private router: Router,
      private route: ActivatedRoute) {

      }


    search(term: string): void {

      this.searchTerm = new SearchTerm('some value','some value');


    }


  }
```

It doesn't matter if I declare the new object within the constructor, or within any function, it always produces a 404 /traceur error and the app won't load.  If I  remove the new declaration the app works.

NG Module section:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  routing,
  HttpModule,
  JsonpModule
],
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  HomeComponent,
  NavComponent,
  ItemSearchComponent,
  SearchComponent,
  routedComponents
],
providers: [
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading     http://localhost:8000/traceur
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange]     (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:794:30)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:38)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:48)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:433:34)
Error loading http://localhost:8000/traceur
Error loading http://localhost:8000/dist/app/item.js as "./item" from
```

Comment: Which angular2 version are you using?

Comment: using version 5

Comment: Then remove `providers: [ItemSearchService],` from @Component and show your `@NgModule({})` section.